# Delete cookie (PHP, JS) works in Firefox, Safari, Opera but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

The question basically explains it all, I'm trying to delete the cookie in PHP and also sending JS to delete the cookie as well, not working ONLY in Chrome...

```
<?php
  unset( $_COOKIE['name'] );
  setcookie('name', '', time() - 3600 ); // empty value and old timestamp
?> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteCookie( name ) {
       document.cookie = name + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
    }
    deleteCookie('name');

</script>
<a href="cookie.php">cookie</a>
```

All help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: Firebug in Firefox shows no errors, PHP error log shows nothing... the only other thing I can see is that chrome seems to be conserving 1 particular value. name=ABCDE ... if I change it to name=ABC then delete name=ABC it will show name=ABCDE, if I delete name=ABCDE it will still show name=ABCDE

Comment: Stuff was posted last year about it but I'm not sure if it got fixed.  It was supposedly a "feature".  Here's a reference for you (comment #8 specifically) https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-bugs/cjt3WwgOJ3c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere during development some wires got crossed, I went into chrome settings and deleted the cookies and all data from my domain:

https://superuser.com/questions/548096/how-can-i-clear-cookies-for-a-single-site

and now it works great! I saw other people on forums with this same issue, I encourage you to do the same...

I don't even send the JS code anymore PHP takes care of it!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try changing the value of the cookie to be something different, when deleted?

That will avoid the problem of setting the expiration date to a date in the past and hoping the browser will delete it.

So, for example, `ABCDE=deleted; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;` instead of `ABCDE=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;`

Now you can check if it was supposed to be deleted, but still exists in Chrome with:

```
if(document.cookie.indexOf('ABCDE=deleted') !== -1) 
{
    // cookie still exists, but was supposed to be deleted
}
```